# jquery plugin to reverse textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

What my aim is to reverse the text witten inside textbox on button click. So far what I have done is like this.
my html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reverse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>mithun</p>
<input name="writehere"  id="ch" type="text" class="jst" />
<input name="check" type="button" value="b1" id="b1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#b1").click(function() {
$('p').reverseText();
});</script>
</body></html>
```

my jquery.reverse.js plugin is

```
(function($) {

// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.reverseText = function(params) {

    // merge default and user parameters

    params = $.extend( {minlength: 0, maxlength: 99999}, params);

    // traverse all nodes
    this.each(function() {

        // express a single node as a jQuery object
        var $t = $(this);

        // find text
        var origText = $t.text(), newText = '';

        // text length within defined limits?
        if (origText.length >= params.minlength &&  origText.length <= params.maxlength) {

            // reverse text
            for (var i = origText.length-1; i >= 0; i--) newText += origText.substr(i, 1);
            $t.text(newText);

        }

    });

    // allow jQuery chaining
    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

it is working if i want to reverse the text of `<p></p>`. but what i want to do is to reverse the text written inside text box with id="ch" on button click.How the plugin will look like to achieve this?
Can any one give me any suggestion how the plugin will be require to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/wspuj5pg/)

```
(function($) {

// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.reverseText = function(params) {

    // merge default and user parameters

    params = $.extend( {minlength: 0, maxlength: 99999}, params);

    // traverse all nodes
    this.each(function() {

        // express a single node as a jQuery object
        var $t = $(this);

        // find text
        var origText = $t.val(), newText = '';

        // text length within defined limits?
        if (origText.length >= params.minlength &&  origText.length <= params.maxlength) {

            // reverse text
            for (var i = origText.length-1; i >= 0; i--) newText += origText.substr(i, 1);
            $t.val(newText);

        }

    });

    // allow jQuery chaining
    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling reverseText function for `p` tag

```
$('p').reverseText();
```

for applying reverseText function to input box use below code

```
 $('#ch').reverseText();
```

also in plugin code need to read value using `.val()` instead of `.text()` because `input` has value in `value` attribute

```
// find text
        var origText = $t.val(), newText = '';
```

**NOTE** - make sure that `id="ch"`must be unique through out the DOM html.